# Issue with data send through curl in php

Tags: php, curl

we have written a curl script in php.

```
$urlFinal="timestamp=".$timeStamp. "&vender_id=8&industry_id=".$companyName."&stationId=".$stationName."&analyserId=".$deviceIdOrSlNoNew."&processValue=".$dataValue."&scaledValue=".$dataValue."&flag=U".htmlspecialchars("&")."parameter=".$paramterName."&unit=".$unitKey;

$url="http://www.example.com/store/WebService.asmx/getdata?".$urlFinal;


echo "<br /><br /><br />";
echo $url;
echo "<br /><br /><br /><br />";

$urlNew=str_replace("&amp;","&",$url);  

echo "<br />".$urlNew;

echo "<br /><br /><br /><br />";



$ch = curl_init($urlNew);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;

echo "<br />".$data;
```

We get following output in browser

http://www.example.com/store/WebService.asmx/getdata?timestamp=2018-08-04:12:00:00.AM&vender_id=18&industry_id=ABC Ltd, Chemical Division&stationId=Abcl Na-hypo Stack&analyserId=ARSN:1853&processValue=4.70&scaledValue=4.70&flag=U&parameter=Cl2&unit=ug/m3

http://www.example.com/store/WebService.asmx/getdata?timestamp=2018-08-04:12:00:00.AM&vender_id=18&industry_id=ABC Industries Ltd, Chemical Division&stationId=Abcl Na-hypo Stack&analyserId=ARSN:1853&processValue=4.70&scaledValue=4.70&flag=U¶meter=Cl2&unit=ug/m3

Bad Request
HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.

Bad Request
HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.

How to fix problem of &para in Curl. the above work perfectly with when we paste following browser address bar

http://www.example.com/store/WebService.asmx/getdata?timestamp=2018-08-04:12:00:00.AM&vender_id=18&industry_id=ABC Ltd, Chemical Division&stationId=Abcl Na-hypo Stack&analyserId=ARSN:1853&processValue=4.70&scaledValue=4.70&flag=U&parameter=Cl2&unit=ug/m3

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use urlencode function before curl_init.

```
string urlencode ( string $str )
```

Like this

```
$url = urlencode($url);
```

and then calling curl_init.

https://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `urlencode` or do any replacements on the actual URL - stuff via GET is supposed to have a proper ampersand (`&`), etc and not the html entity or percent escape code equivalent.

You DO need to do it on individual data items - so your `$companyName` etc. need to be URL encoded, THEN glued together with the variable names to build the entire GET request

Also, I'll just ask - are you using cURL for a GET request because using http with the various `fopen` type calls (including `file_get_contents` is disabled?  Because for GET requests, `file_get_contents` is sooo much easier than cURL ...

Comment: I am sending data to another user who given us this url & parameters. I need to send data via automated script in every 15 minutes.